# How to calculate the remaining size of the widget from flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout, calculation

I created a flutter widget in order
Container ~> Columns [
Containers
Expanded ~> Stack ~> MaterialApp ~> Scaffold ,
Container(
],
I tried with the media query size height but got the result screen height throughout the app,

how do i get the rest of the child stack height?

Comment: can you explain why you are using `MaterialApp` middle of widget tree?

Comment: I want to display the app inside the app, so I need that, and I already know the remaining size using the layout builder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) widget. It gives the property constraints, which is the available constraints for that particular level.